# logo in the first page only

Tags: beamer, titles, themes

I want to insert the logo in the title page only. However, it displays on all pages!
How can I make these two figurs display as logo in the title page only?

I type in the preamble:

```
\logo{%
   \includegraphics[scale=.2]{fig1.pdf}\hspace*{4.75cm}~%
   \includegraphics[scale=.2]{fig2.jpg}\hspace*{0.75cm}%
   }
```

then

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}
...
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I use `\logo{includegraphics{Image/linuxLogo.png}}` but image is appeared in slides.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The command to be used to display the logo only in the titlepage is `\titlegraphic`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{Me}
\title{The title}
\institute{My institute}

% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}\hspace*{4.75cm}~%
   \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test 1}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test 2}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I report the first two frames:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was by far the best way to display logo only on the first page. I did, however, played with the `\vspace{+ or - ...cm}` and the `\hspace{+ or - ...cm}` to try and position the logo where I wanted them to go. The other thing I did was to ensure by reducing size or words of my title text so that it doesn't take up too many lines as this reduces the space at the bottom of the page where the logo needs to go. Many thanks

Comment: @Richard: notice that there are other ways, for example customizing directly the `titlepage` template. See also as reference [Logo situated only on titlepage of Beamer presentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68652/logo-situated-only-on-titlepage-of-beamer-presentation)

Comment: Dear Downvoter: would you like to explain why the answer deserves a downvote? I'm interested to see if there are any weak points and improve the answer accordingly. Thanks :)

Comment: While this answer solves the asker's problem, I think it does not answer the question: How to make the logo - declared by `\logo{}` only appear on the title slide. `\titlegraphic` should be used for what it says: place a title graphic, not the logo. A better way to solve the asker's problem would be in the style files where you could turn off the logo placement.

Comment: @mpe: I'm afraid, I disagree. The `\titlegraphic` macro should be used exactly for the purpose of setting a logo only in the title page, so I'm wondering, why one should modify `\logo` when it exists `\titlegraphic`? Take into account that very often logo and title graphic are used interchangeably.

Comment: \titlegraphic is for including a graphic on the title page, such as highlighting/previewing an interesting result from the talk. \logo is for including an institutional logo that may or may not be intended to appear on other slides (different conventions exist for first slide, every slide, or first slide and conclusion). They are different and this answer will not work for someone who wants to use both for separate purposes.

Comment: That is correct, but if one wants to display an istitutional logo _only_ on the first page, _this_ the simplest way to go. The _only_ is what I implicitly assumed while answering. Of course there are other tricks, however none of them is as simple as this one. But you have a point with your comment ;)

Comment: The trouble is that every question about \logo gets answered with a hack or workaround and it makes it very hard to search for documentation on the actual \logo command.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino You can also put `\vspace{0cm}` in your example, so that anyone(I need also) can use this if needed.

Comment: @alhelal: How would that help to address the OP question?

Comment: I have never known this command until I found your solution, that is helpful!

Comment: Hello, why do we need to include `~%` in `\hspace*{4.75cm}~%`? What is the purpose, please? Thank  you.

Comment: The `hspace` is just to separate the two images and the `~` is pretty redundant here.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue and didn't like the `titlegraphic` solution. Here is what I did:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{Me}
\title{The title}
\institute{My institute}

% logo of my university  
\logo{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}\hspace*{8cm}~%
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\logo{}

\begin{frame}{Test 1}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test 2}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gave me the following output:

[image: Titlepage]
[image: First frame]
[image: Second frame]