# Logo situated only on titlepage of Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

How to put logo only on the title page of Beamer presentation between the title and subtitle? I'm using

```
\title{Title}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo}}
\subtitle{\textbf{Subtitle}}
```

but the logo comes after date.

Comment: Related: [logo in the first page only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61051/logo-in-the-first-page-only)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
\title[Title]{Title\\[1em]\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo}}
```

it's important to use the optional argument with the title once again so the right title would be used in other parts of the document (foot/headline, for example).

Another option would be to redefine the `title page` template to include the logo in the desired position:

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \vskip0.25em%
      {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
  \end{centering}
  \vfill
}
\makeatother
```

and then simply use `\titlegraphic`:

```
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo}}
```

Answer (score 5):

As a logo is usually associated with an organization, I use the `\institute` macro to put the logo on title frame:

```
\institute[short name]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo}}
```

(*short name* is usually printed on every slide depending on the theme used.)

But this logo is not *between* title and subtitle... The default order is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{title}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\institute{institute}
\author{author}
\date{date}
\titlegraphic{titlegraphic}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the requirement is that the logo should be placed between the title and the subtitle and your solution doesn't do this.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Exact... This detail is not explicit in the title of the question.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is this:

```latex
\title{title}
\author{authorname}
\institute{\includegraphics[scale=0.035]{logo} \\Physics Department\\ IIT Bombay}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.