# Show and hide the logo in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm realizing my first presentation in beamer. I'm using the CambridgeUS theme, and I want to

- show the logo of my institute in the center of the first frame
- hide the logo in the following frame

For now, my document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}
\date{The Date}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{TheLogo}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
The Frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which show the logo on the right in every frame.
What have I to edit / add to reach my goals?

Comment: Is [logo in the first page only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61051/13304) a possible duplicate?

Comment: Only in part. I want to hide the show the logo in the first page only, AND center the logo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `\logo`, use `\titlegraphic`; the former will place the logo in all frames and in the bottom right; the latter places the logo just in the title page and centered at the bottom:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}
\date{The Date}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also would like to show the logo on the center instead of the right: how?

Comment: @Andrea Ah, yes. Give me some seconds :)

Comment: @Andrea Please see my updated answer. I wasn't sure, however if your first pages is a title page, so let me know if some modification is required.